# UIScrollView with UIImageView gesture click only work on first visible images

Tags: swift

I have UIScrollView and I add few UIImageView, it's comment ViewController and click on images only work for first two images or for only images which are visible when scroll Y = 0. Even if image is half visible when scroll Y = 0 then first half of image click works and second half when you try to click nothing happen. Any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by implementing touch position on scroll and I handle click on image if it's clicked on image ...